# How to render react component as plain text

Tags: reactjs

Sorry about stupid question.

I have react app.
Writing documentation for my components.
And I want to insert my component as plain text and I can't find way.
ex:

```
import Input from "../components/input";
function DocumentationPage () {
  return (<div>
    Input:
    usage:
    <code> <Input type='login' label={'Login'} value={value} onChange={onChange}></Input></code>
    <Input type='login' label={'Login'}></Input>
  </div>)
}
```

So I want <Input...> inside the code tag to be rendered as plain text.

Comment: One of the ways how to it - assign it to variable. But in this case I lost some marking
ex:
const input = `
    <Input type='login' label={'Login'} value={props.value} onChange={onChange}></Input>
    `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap `<Input type='login' label={'Login'} value={value} onChange={onChange}></Input>` in brackets and quotes to render it as a string, like this:

```
import Input from "../components/input";
function DocumentationPage () {
  return (<div>
    Input:
    usage:
    <code>{'<Input type='login' label={'Login'} value={value} onChange={onChange}></Input>'}</code>
    <Input type='login' label={'Login'}></Input>
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: Gonna need to use backticks or double quotes

Comment: It works for me. Thank you!
(as usial, a lot of things were tryed but not this)

Comment: @Abraham Labkovsky You can use single quotes, double quotes or backticks.

Comment: I am aware of how to create strings. Try logging `'<Input type='login' label={'Login'} value={value} onChange={onChange}></Input>'` in the browser if you want to know what my comment was meant to correct

Comment: @Abraham Labkovsky Sorry, didn't check if the string contained other single quotes. Great catch.